# Whats the best practice to save and load array of struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, save

I am looking for advice to save my array of structures, so they are available at start and can be easily accessed and updated.

All tutorials I have watched have only 1 instance of struct, so I keep failing on implementing array of structures.

Structure of data is:

```swift
    struct Stock : Codable {
        let ticker : String
        let amount : Double
        var boughtAt : Double
        var totalValue : Double
        var realTimePrice : Double
        var float : Double
        var type : String
    }

    var stocksArray = [Stock]()
```

Comment: You should explain the use case as well as what you have tried till now for us to better answer your question

Comment: use coredata :)

Comment: It's important to understand how much data you are trying to store. Also, what technique have you been watching (i.e., where have you been trying to store the data)?

Comment: First of all `UserDefaults` is discouraged for this kind of user data, you can use encoded data as JSON or Property List file in documents folder, Core Data, other databases like Realm, Firebase, MYSQL etc. or CloudKit

Comment: thanks for idea @J.Doe :) I actually made it work trough CoreData.

Comment: thank you all for input and ideas, I wanted to save this kind of data so it can be loaded for my UITable on start of application and easily used to perform further calculations and saved again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `struct Stock` conforms to `Codable`, you can easily store the `array [Stock]` in `UserDefaults` as `data` using `JSONEncoder`, i.e.

```
var stocksArray = [Stock]()
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(stocksArray)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "stocksArray")
} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

Similarly, you can fetch from `UserDefaults` using `JSONDecoder` like,

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "stocksArray") {
    do {
        let arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Stock].self, from: data)
        print(arr)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is one way to store your `array`. There are other ways as well - `CoreData`, `File` etc.

Comment: This works perfectly ! Very short and easy to understand for me.  Most importantly once data gets loaded, it is structured in exactly same way as I need them , thank you !

Comment: Binary `property lists` may be better format for storage in `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,
You can convert your Struct to Dictionary type and add that dictionary in to NSArray and save that array to Document directory of phone.

Example,

```
struct Stock {
    var ticker : String = ""
    var amount : Double = 0.0
    var boughtAt : Double = 0.0
    var totalValue : Double = 0.0
    var realTimePrice : Double = 0.0
    var float : Double = 0.0
    var type : String = ""

    var json:Dictionary<String,Any> {
        set{
            self.ticker = newValue["ticker"] as! String
            self.amount = newValue["amount"] as! Double
            self.boughtAt = newValue["boughtAt"] as! Double
            self.totalValue = newValue["totalValue"] as! Double
            self.realTimePrice = newValue["realTimePrice"] as! Double
            self.float = newValue["float"] as! Double
            self.type = newValue["type"] as! String
        }
        get {
            return ["ticker":self.ticker,"amount":self.amount,"boughtAt":self.boughtAt,"totalValue":self.totalValue,"realTimePrice":self.realTimePrice,"float":self.float,"type":self.type]
        }
    }

    init(withJSON json:Dictionary<String,Any>) {
        self.json = json
    }
}
//Now, get dictionary from object and add it into array.
let stock = Stock(withJSON: [:])
let json = self.stock.json
let array = NSArray(arrayLiteral: json)

//Now, you can save NSArray to file.
array.write(toFile: "file path.plist", atomically: true)

//You can get array from plist file,
let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: "file path.plist")
```

Comment: thank you for this idea :) however, I would be using that data for UITable (as I forgot to mention), so I would have to recreate my structure before using it.